# How to update Ruby on Rails app after deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Let's say I have deployed my Rails app on a VPS, and everything works fine. MySQL is populating.

Then I wanna change the functionality or view of the app. What should I do next?

Probably using CentOS, Passanger, nginx, MySQL and GIT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several tools that can help you with this kind of things, I think the most widely used is [Capistrano](http://github.com/capistrano/capistrano). But in essence it's nothing magical. Upload the new code and it should be ready to go. If you have done any modifications to the database, you should take the app offline before upgrading it, then run migrations, and go back online again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/) to deploy new versions of your application.

The idea is to develop locally, run and test the application locally.
And when you're ready to deploy, you use capistrano to update the source code in the production server.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to understand about [database migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) too.